# Both sidebars to wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to modify wordpress theme "donovan" and want to customize the theme
This theme has got only right sidebar

https://wordpress.org/themes/donovan/

I want to add both sidebars to it like this, Highlighted with green border
https://beautifulthemer.com/wp-content/uploads/two-sidebars-graphic.jpg

but I don't know how to customize it using coding/plugin, 
I want to achieve this mostly through coding

In more details:

I want to customize the sidebar in WordPress Theme. Right now I want 2 sidebar (right and left) and middle space for content/post. As shown in above URL picture.

"donovan" theme has only one sidebar and I want to add more sidebar into it

Comment: So, what's your question? It's not clear from what you posted.

Comment: I want to customize the sidebar in WordPress Theme. Right now I want 2 sidebar (right and left) and middle space for content/post. As shown in above URL picture. "donovan" theme has only one sidebar and I want to add more sidebar into it

Comment: In that case, you should [create a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) to extend the Donovan theme, then [register a new sidebar](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_sidebar/), and then add it to your new theme.